# Error Importing Plotly Widgets?

Tags: python, plotly

Very strange error here that I haven't seen anywhere else, I am trying to import Plotly widgets and keep coming up with this error.

```
from plotly.widgets import *


IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.

<IPython.core.display.Javascript object>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    from plotly.widgets import *
  File "/Users/Clinder/Downloads/task/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/widgets/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from plotly.widgets.graph_widget import GraphWidget
  File "/Users/Clinder/Downloads/task/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/widgets/graph_widget.py", line 31, in <module>
    class GraphWidget(widgets.DOMWidget):
  File "/Users/Clinder/Downloads/task/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/shimmodule.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: DOMWidget
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I have looked through the files but cannot seem to find the issue as well as reinstalling this package.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Did you install jupyter?

Comment: I dont think I did, will try that as soon as im home. Thanks! I'm on mac os

Answer (score 0):

`plotly.widgets` expects iPython and Jupyter notebook to be installed, see this related [bug report](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps/issues/48). Try installing jupyter (`pip3 install jupyter`) and the import should work.